# ROS on iMX6 based SBC

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am considering using ROS on an element14 iMX6 SBC.  Has anyone had any experience with this combination or any iMX6 processor board?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59950/ros-on-imx6-based-sbc/) by [DelWilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4605/delwilson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No direct experience, but if you can run linux on it you should be able to run ROS. You may have to compile everything from source.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0